# Python3 preparing packages for PyPi not including submodules

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module, pypi, python-packaging

Notes:

1. I am using Python v3.6
2. I have read the documentation regarding [Modules and Packages](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)
3. I have read and gone through the [Packaging project tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/)
4. I have looked at the [Sample Project](https://github.com/pypa/sampleproject) (different from tutorial project)

I have a simple package I want to make

```
myPackage/                      The project directory
    myPackage/                  Top-level package
      __init__.py               Initialize my package
      myClass.py                a file with a single class in it

    setup.py
    README.md
    ...
    dist/
```

where `myClass.py` is just

```
class myClass:
    __init__(self):
        print('here')
```

and my `myPackage/__init__.py` file is just like the demo

```
name = "myPackage"
```

I have successful got it on pypi and pip installed it.

I can `import myPackage` but unlike the tutorial where

```
example_pkg.name
```

works,

```
myPackage.name
```

does not.

The above linked Sample project doesn't exactly elaborate any more on the **init**.py file.

So my question is as follows:

suppose one had a package like that under the documentation for Modules and Packages:

```
sound/                          Top-level package
      __init__.py               Initialize the sound package
      formats/                  Subpackage for file format conversions
              __init__.py
              wavread.py
              wavwrite.py
              aiffread.py
              aiffwrite.py
              auread.py
              auwrite.py
              ...
      effects/                  Subpackage for sound effects
              __init__.py
              echo.py
              surround.py
              reverse.py
              ...
      filters/                  Subpackage for filters
              __init__.py
              equalizer.py
              vocoder.py
              karaoke.py
              ...
```

where the actual file structure is (following the packaging project tutorial)

```
sound/
    sound/ (Top-level package)
        __init__.py
        ...
    dist/
    build/
    sound.egg/
    README.md
    ...
```

What goes in `sound/__init__.py` (or `myPackage/__init__.py`) so that I can import it and access the functions, submodules, and classes therein?

Sorry for being an noob at python packaging.

```
# contents of setup.py
import setuptools

with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()

setuptools.setup(
    name="progil",
    version="0.0.4",
    author="name",
    author_email="name@web",
    description="Progress In Line",
    long_description=long_description,
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    url="https://pypi.org/project/progil/",
    packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
)
```

Comment: Is your `myClass.py` file accurate? You're missing a `class` keyword.

Comment: @Chris just a mock up here, I wrote in the question, so please forgive those errors.

Comment: Please [edit] the question then. We have no way of knowing which errors are relevant and which we should ignore. What does "doesn't work" mean? Does `myPackage.name` raise an `AttributeError`? Does it contain `None`? An empty string?

Comment: @wim https://pypi.org/project/progil/

Comment: @Chris done, and NameError

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sanity checking the distribution's top-level import names by using my project [johnnydep](https://github.com/wimglenn/johnnydep):

```
# pip install johnnydep
$ johnnydep progil --fields name summary versions_available import_names
name    summary           versions_available    import_names
------  ----------------  --------------------  --------------
progil  Progress In Line  0.0.2, 0.0.3, 0.0.4   progril
```

You are going to kick yourself.  It looks like you named the distribution:

```
progil
```

But you named the package in source code

```
progril
```

pip installing `progil` and importing `progril` works.  You didn't notice at setup time because you've used `find_packages()` and, actually, there is no reason the distribution name needs to match the package name(s).

Comment: oh no. New keyboard and laziness to thoroughly check before posting. My apologies. Follow-up can you link me to a in-depth (for beginner) guide  for what to do with the main packages `__init__.py` file? and if I have a file in a submodule`myClass.py` which just has `class myClass` is there a way to import it from the top level module?

Comment: @SumNeuron Please try a few of the obvious things yourself first, and if they don't work, open a new question. SO is trying not to be a chat site.